# Using fillna(0) then replace on 0.00 to convert to 0 is not working

Tags: python, dataframe

I am using fillna(0) on a dataframe and then using .round(2) on the columns to get 2 decimal places. I would like to show the zero values as 0 rather 0.00, but when I use this code they don't get replaced:

```
main_framing_df = main_framing_df.replace(to_replace = 0.00, value = 0)
```

Using iloc I can see that the 0.00 value is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if int(x)==x:
    f(int(x)) #do something with int(x)
else:
    f(x) #do something with x
```